# How to derive $J_v(x)$

Tags: derivatives, bessel-functions

I've seen many sources say that $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}J_v(x) = J_{v-1}(x) - \frac{v}{x}J_v(x)$, but every time I try to derive it, I get the conjugate, $\frac{v}{x}J_v(x) - J_{v-1}(x)$. Could someone walk me through the steps to arrive at this derivative, so I may see where I went wrong?

$$
J_v(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{(-1)^n}{\Pi(v+n)n!}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2n+v}}\\
\begin{align}
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}J_v(x)
& = \sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{(-1)^n}{\Pi(v+n)n!}\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2n+v}} \\
& = \sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{(-1)^n(2n+v)}{2\Pi(v+n)n!}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2n+v-1}} \\
& = \sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{(-1)^nn}{\Pi(v+n)n!}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2n+v-1}} + \frac{v}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{(-1)^n}{\Pi(v+n)n!}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2n+v-1}} \\
& = \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{-1}\left[\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{(-1)^n}{\Pi(v+n)(n-1)!}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2n+v}} + \frac{v}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{(-1)^n}{\Pi(v+n)n!}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2n+v}}\right] \\
& = \left(\frac{2}{x}\right)\left[\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{\Pi(v+n-1)n!}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2(n-1)+v}} + \frac{v}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{(-1)^n}{\Pi(v+n)n!}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2n+v}}\right] \\
& = -\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{(-1)^n}{\Pi((v-1)+n)n!}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2n+(v-1)}} + \frac{v}{x}\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{(-1)^n}{\Pi(v+n)n!}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2n+v}} \\
& = \frac{v}{x}J_v(x) - J_{v-1}(x)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I would suggest putting the work you have up there first

Comment: @DanZimm There you go.

Comment: It is much easier is you instead use $2n+\nu = 2(n+\nu) - \nu$. That way you avoid having to change the summation index.

Comment: When you do your change of indices from the 4th to 5th line you put $k = n+1$ so that $n \to k-1, n-1 \to k-2$ but you have it so that $n-1 \to n$, something is fishy there. Next when you fact $2/x$ back into the first sum on the 6th line the exponent on $x/2$ should be $2(n-1) + v - 1 = 2n + v - 3 \neq 2n + v - 1$ which is what you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$$\frac{dJ_{\nu}}{dx} = \sum_{m=0} \frac{(-1)^m}{m!\Gamma(m+\nu+1)} (2m +\nu)\frac{x^{2m+\nu-1}}{2^{2m+\nu}} = \sum_{m=0} \frac{(-1)^m}{m!\Gamma(m+\nu)} \frac{2m +\nu}{2m+2\nu}\left({x\over 2}\right)^{2m+\nu-1}$$

where we have used $\Gamma(m+\nu+1)=(m+\nu)\Gamma(m+\nu)$. Now use $$\frac{2m+\nu}{2m+2\nu} = 1 -\frac{\nu}{2(m+\nu)}$$

The sum splits into two sums. The first sum is

$$\sum_{m=0} \frac{(-1)^m}{m!\Gamma(m+\nu)}\cdot 1 \cdot\left({x\over 2}\right)^{2m+\nu-1} \equiv J_{\nu -1}$$

and the second sum is

$$~~~~~~\sum_{m=0} \frac{(-1)^m}{m!\Gamma(m+\nu)}\cdot \left(-\frac{\nu}{2(m+\nu)} \right)\cdot\left({x\over 2}\right)^{2m+\nu-1} \\= -\frac{\nu}{x}\sum_{m=0} \frac{(-1)^m}{m!\Gamma(m+\nu+1)} \cdot\left({x\over 2}\right)^{2m+\nu} \equiv -\frac{\nu}{x}J_\nu$$

where we have used $\Gamma(m+\nu)(m+\nu) = \Gamma(m+\nu+1)$.

Comment: I see, thanks for clarifying. Where might the error have been in my solution?

Answer (score 2):

I think it is a bit faster to use the relation:
$$ J_\nu(x) = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos(\nu t-x\sin t)\,dt \tag{1}$$
from which:
$$\frac{d}{dx} J_\nu(x) = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin t\,\sin(\nu t-x\sin t)\,dt = \frac{1}{2}\left(J_{\nu-1}(x)-J_{\nu+1}(x)\right)$$
follows by the Briggs formulas. Hence we have to prove:
$$J_{\nu-1}(x)-\frac{\nu}{x}J_{\nu}(x)=\frac{1}{2}\left(J_{\nu-1}(x)-J_{\nu+1}(x)\right)$$
or:
$$J_{\nu-1}(x)-\frac{2\nu}{x}J_{\nu}(x)+J_{\nu+1}(x)=0\tag{2}$$
that follows from:
$$J_{\nu+1}(x)+J_{\nu-1}(x)=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos(x\sin t)\cos(\nu t-x\sin t)\,dt =\frac{2\nu}{x}J_{\nu}(x).$$